# what is the best way to delete a bidirectional relationship in jpa?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, orm

I have a class called `AssessmentCenter`, it has many to many relationships with my customers class `Interviewer`, customer class `Candidate` and customer class `Recruiter`. It also has a one to many relationship with customer class `Interview`. All of them has a bidirectional relationship (so each class hold reference object(s) of each other). To give you a idea of how it looks like, check the segment of the code in the `AssessmentCener` class below:
[image]

Now, the problem is, when I try to delete an `AssessmentCenter`, I need to manually remove those references that hold by each object, otherwise, it will cause error. For example, if I want to remove an instance of `AssessmentCenter` from database, then I need to do following:

1. delete all objects in `List<Interviewer>` -> then for each deleted `Interviewer` object, I need to delete the `AssessmentCenter` object that `Interviewer` object holds.
2. Repeat the same thing for other 3 (for `Candidate` which has one to many relationship, the idea is same except on the interview end, it will only need to delete `AssessmentCenter` object once).

The following code show the process:
[image]

As you can see, this process is very tedious and error-prone, as I need to make sure I delete all the relationships whenever I want to remove an `AssessmentCenter`.
Therefore, my question is, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This looks very complicated. The answer below shows that you can just use JPA's cascade remove to have the delete cascade over relationships in an object graph which may be what you want - but there should be no need to iterate over collections, call remove on them, and then saveAll on those same lists and pieces - which begs the question.. what are you really doing in those removeXXX calls? Are you just nulling out references? If you don't want those pieces deleted, then yes, you have to tell JPA how to handle any references to the entity you wish to remove, which means nulling them out

Comment: If you do this in the repository, within a single transaction, the code would be cleaner with no need to call other repositories. The findById would return a managed assessmentCenter and all changes to all interviewers, interviews and candidates would then also be managed in that transaction and get picked up when it commits. You'd just need to call em.remove instead of the save and deleteById calls.

Comment: Hi Chris, you are right, I am just trying to null them. For example, if my "AssessmentCenter" hold a object of "Candidate", and candidate hold an object of "AssessmentCenter", than I have to manually remove the "Candidate" from "AsssessmentCenter" then "AssessmentCenter" from "Candidate", in this case, would you recommend using the "remove" cascadeType? Thanks

Comment: The remove cascade option will cascade JPA delete/remove calls over the mapping's references, so you only use it when you want referenced entities to be deleted too - counter to what this code is doing. Cascade remove and orphan removal are for situations where you are trimming a branch and don't want to have to manually delete each leaf on that branch yourself. If you want to trim the branch but keep the leaves, you have to pluck each off and decide where/how to keep them. You are forced to null out foreign keys referencing AssessmentCenter when you want to remove it and keep the rest.

Comment: The AssessmentCenter should be aware of what is and how it fits into the object graph, and this type of logic is what normally goes into repository or service level constructs. So the AssessmentCenterService delete operation would be aware of all that needs to be done to remove AssessmentCenter - this might be just a JPA remove call, but more than likely includes lifecycle maintenance such as clean up  of references, cache invalidation and any other notifications/auditing that must happen around this. You don't have to null references from AssessmentCenter; just references to AssessmentCenter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must null out reference to AssessmentCenter - it is the draw back and strength of referential integrity that these references keep you from removing the referenced data. While you may think of having to handle each reference yourself as tedious, it really does protect your application from errors - you must think of what you want to happen to each and every reference you have in your graph when one of the nodes disappears and ensure it is appropriately handled. Even when the database has mechanisms in the tables to null out foreign keys, this can (and will) leave the object model inconsistent with what is in the database. This is the best practice, as even before JPA there was a strong push that database objects be cached, which requires maintain the data in those objects and keeping them in synch with the database. Not doing so leads to all sorts of trouble and confusion, mostly seen in these forums around bidirectional relationships. And lets face it, constructs buried in DB logic future devs may not notice leads to data unknowingly being orphaned in legacy apps, and makes those legacy apps much more difficult to maintain.

I normally see applications push to put such lifecycle logic either in repository or Service level classes. In this case, it would make sense to have a AssessmentCenterService class with specialized methods to handle what is required when you need to remove AssessmentCenter instances for various use cases your application may have - this then becomes the central spot for lifecycle operations around the AssessmentCenter data. AssessmentCenter references to other entities, and an entity's reference to AssessmentCenter may not always need to be cleaned up, but a service object would be the spot to know and make that decision. It should be the spot to know that when removing an AssesmentCenter, all interviews it took should be cleaned up (deleted as well) but candidates themselves need to be kept. It should null out Candidate references to this AssesmentCenter, or replace them with a holding AssesmentCenter reference, or some how give an indication in that data that the original center they applied no longer exists. Lifecycle management on the data might extend past the database as well - any caches or other VMs holding this data may need to be notified of the relevant changes to this data, so they can invalidate or refresh their view of it, and any external artifacts like file storage cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

try using `CascadeType.REMOVE` in your `ManyToMany` and `OneToMany` relationships, it deletes child entities whenever the deletion of its parent happens.

e.g.

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "accessmentCenters", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
@JsonIgnore
private List<Interviewer> interviewers;
```

For `OneToMany` relationships, you can also try setting `orphanRemoval = true`:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "accessmentCenter", orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonIgnore
private List<Interview> interviews;
```

Afterwards, in your `deleteAcById` method, you will just need to call `accessmentCenterRepository.deleteById`, and it will take care of the children entities for you.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think this is the best practice, see this article: https://thorben-janssen.com/avoid-cascadetype-delete-many-assocations/#:~:text=You%20get%20even%20bigger%20problems,database%20records%20than%20you%20expected. In short, I don't want to delete my child or parent when I delete one of them because that might cause some unexpected instance remove.

Comment: correct me if wrong, so your desired outcome was when you delete an `AccessmentCenter`, you just want the related fields (i.e. `interviewers`, `interviews`) to nullify the corresponding `accessmentCenter` field?

Comment: yes, but my current solution is manually delete them which is very tedious and error-prone. Is there any better method for this?